# Adding calculated column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 10 columns.  I want to add a new column 'age_bmi' which should be a calculated column multiplying 'age' * 'bmi'.  age is an INT, bmi is a FLOAT.

That then creates the new dataframe with 11 columns.

Something I am doing isn't quite right.  I think it's a syntax issue.  Any ideas?

Thanks

```
df2['age_bmi'] = df(['age'] * ['bmi'])
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

try `df2['age_bmi'] = df.age * df.bmi`.

You're trying to call the dataframe as a function, when you need to get the values of the columns, which you can access by key like a dictionary or by property if it's a lowercase name with no spaces that doesn't match a built-in DataFrame method.

Someone linked this in a comment the other day and it's pretty awesome. I recommend giving it a watch, even if you don't do the exercises: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5JnMutdy6Fw

Comment: Perfect thanks Cory, I will check out that video as well

Comment: I checked out the first hour of that video so far, it is fantastic . Thank you for that link!  The guy has a great flow to his teaching

Comment: Awesome, glad you're enjoying it. I'm still watching it myself, but in the first hour I was like "oh sh!t!" like 3 times in awe over the cool stuff you can do with it.

Comment: This eitther gives me an error that `df2` is undefined or if I use `df` it says: ```
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: Is there a way the columns are auto-computed? as in the excel like columns? Where affecting one column or row would auto-affect the values in other columns that depend on them? Without having to run apply or anything explicilty over the frame?

Comment: @NikhilMulley I don't know the answer to that. You'd have better luck posting another question.

Answer (score 26):

As pointed by Cory, you're calling a dataframe as a function, that'll not work as you expect. Here are 4 ways to multiple two columns, in most cases you'd use the first method.

```
In [299]: df['age_bmi'] = df.age * df.bmi
```

or,

```
In [300]: df['age_bmi'] = df.eval('age*bmi')
```

or,

```
In [301]: df['age_bmi'] = pd.eval('df.age*df.bmi')
```

or,

```
In [302]: df['age_bmi'] = df.age.mul(df.bmi)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have combined age & bmi inside a bracket and treating df as a function rather than a dataframe. Here df should be used to call the columns as a property of DataFrame-

```
df2['age_bmi'] = df['age'] *df['bmi']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df2 = df.assign(age_bmi = df['age'] * df['bmi'])
```