# Logarithmic operation on pandas dataframe-Key value error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as shown below.it's name is 'df_thd_funct' .I need to apply logarithmic equation on xvalue columns and need to create a new column.Below is my code.

```
df_thd_funct['sensi'] = 20*(np.log(df_thd_funct.xvalues/1.44)) 

xvalues SFM_376_1.62_-40    
0.0189     0.0190                       
0.0200     0.0187               
0.0225     0.0167              
0.0239     0.0191
```

The error I am getting is given below. What am I missing?

[image]

My complete code is given below.

```
df_thd_funct = pd.read_csv("A2_THD_Ratio_Stepped_Sweep_Corners_PVT_lab01.txt",delim_whitespace=True,index_col=False)
df_thd_funct.set_index('xvalues', inplace=True)
check_for_nan = df_thd_funct.isnull().values.any()
df_thd_funct = df_thd_funct.T
print (check_for_nan)
df_thd_funct.head()
```

After running `df_thd_funct['sensi'] = df_thd_funct['xvalues'].apply(lambda x: 20*(np.log(x/1.44)))`

The new error obtained is given below.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393143/2570277) answer help?

Comment: `20 * (df['xvalues'] / 1.44).apply(np.log)`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Thnak you ,but I am getting this error "KeyError: 'xvalues'"

Answer (score 1):

You can't give `np.log` a pd.Series as argument, you have to use `lambda` function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'xvalues':[0.0189,0.0200,0.0225,0.0239]})

df['sensi'] = df['xvalues'].apply(lambda x: 20*(np.log(x/1.44)))
```

Output:

```
   xvalues      sensi
0   0.0189 -86.664729
1   0.0200 -85.533322
2   0.0225 -83.177662
3   0.0239 -81.970399
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question which shows how I read the data frame and the new error obtained after running the code df['sensi'] = df['xvalues'].apply(lambda x: 20*(np.log(x/1.44)))

Comment: Because the lambda function take the 'xvalues' column as argument, but you set that column as index

Comment: Correct xvalues is my index. Unfortunately I can't change that.May I know how to solve this

Comment: Ypu can just perform the log calc and THEN set 'xvalues' as index