# Overwrite a value in a pandas dataframe column based on a calculation function applied to it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, overwrite

From the following DataFrame:

```
worktime = 1440
person = [11,22,33,44,55]
begin_date = '2019-10-01'
shift= [1,2,3,1,2]
pause = [90,0,85,70,0]
occu = [60,0,40,20,0]
time_u = [50,40,80,20,0]
time_a = [84.5,0.0,10.5,47.7,0.0]
time_p = 0
time_q = [35.9,69.1,0.0,0.0,84.4]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(begin_date, periods=len(person)),'person':person,'shift':shift,'worktime':worktime,'pause':pause,'occu':occu, 'time_u':time_u,'time_a':time_a,'time_p ':time_p,'time_q':time_q,})
```

Output:

```
    date      person  shift worktime pause  occu    time_u  time_a  time_p  time_q 
0   2019-10-01  11      1   1440       90   60        50     84.5      0     35.9
1   2019-10-02  22      2   1440        0    0        40      0.0      0     69.1
2   2019-10-03  33      3   1440       85   40        80     10.5      0      0.0
3   2019-10-04  44      1   1440       70   20        20     47.7      0      0.0
4   2019-10-05  55      2   1440        0    0         0      0.0      0     84.4
```

I am looking for a suitable function that takes the already contained value of the columns and uses it in a calculation and then overwrites it with the result of the calculation.

It concerns the columns time_u, time_a, time_p and time_q and should be applied according to the following principle:

`time_u = worktime - pause - occu - (existing value of time_u)` 
`time_a = (new value of time_u) - time_a` 
`time_p = (new value of time_a) - time_p`
`time_q = (new value of time_p)- time_q`

Is there a possible function that could be used here?

Using this formula manually, the output would look like this:

```
    date      person  shift worktime pause  occu    time_u  time_a  time_p  time_q 
0   2019-10-01  11      1   1440       90   60       1240    1155.5  1155.5  1119.6
1   2019-10-02  22      2   1440        0    0       1400    1400    1400    1330.9
2   2019-10-03  33      3   1440       85   40       1235    1224.5  1224.5  1224.5
3   2019-10-04  44      1   1440       70   20       1330    1282.3  1282.3  1282.3
4   2019-10-05  55      2   1440        0    0       1440    1440    1440    1355.6
```

Unfortunately, this task is way beyond my skill level, so any help in setting up the appropriate function would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393123/adding-calculated-column-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply the relationships you have supplied sequentially. Or are you looking for something else? By the way, you put an extra space at the end of 'time_p'

```
df['time_u'] = df['worktime'] - df['pause'] - df['occu'] - df['time_u']
df['time_a'] = df['time_u'] - df['time_a']
df['time_p'] = df['time_a'] - df['time_p']
df['time_q'] = df['time_p'] - df['time_q']
```